# get express params in an intercepting middleware

Tags: javascript, express

I would like to intercept a req.params item in an interception layer:

let's say I have an express server application instance:

```
const app = express();
```

with an interception layer:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params.myParam);
    next();
})
```

and many endpoints like this one:

```
app.get('/anything/:myParam', (req, res) => res.send('hello'))
```

this logs 'undefined' which is quite natural because when the interception middleware within the "use" is executed, the param name has not been defined yet. But I really need to known in this interception layer the value of myParam parameter with these constraints:

- I known how the parameter is supposed to be named in the intercepted endpoints (myParam)
- I can't know how the url is structured in the intercepted endpoints (can be /anything/:myParam, or /:myParam/anything and so on...)

Does anyone know a solution for that case ?

Comment: Why not use `app.get('/path/with/:myParam', yourMiddleware, (req, res) => ...)`?

Comment: it would pick it up depending on where your app.use is

Comment: ... https://replit.com/@lcherone/69166665

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the suggestion. That would be a nice solution if yourMiddleware could be added automatically to each endpoint. In my context adding it on each endpoint is not possible

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you very much for the code sample: that's indeed a nice solution, however I forgot to mention in the constraints that I need the interception process to run before the endpoint !...

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @indrajaj26 about using app.param() leads me on a working solution.

Here is the way I'm proceeding:

```
/** express application */
const app = express();

// Interception layer
app.param('myParam', (req, res, next, myParam) => {
/* Store myParam into something reusable (like locals as suggested by @nullromo for instance).
 * I'm using zonejs in my case: creating a forked zone with myParam stored in zone properties.
 */
    next();
});

// Consuming intercepted data. Anywhere in the callstack of any endpoint using "myParam" as request parameter:
console.log(Zone.current.getZoneWith('myParam')?.get('myParam'));
```

Thanks everyone for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to pass the middleware function when defining the route.

Example:

```js
function middleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.myParam);
    next();
}

app.get('/path', middleware, function(req, res) {
    ...
});
```

Full example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function middleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.myParam);
    next();
}

app.get('/path', middleware, function(req, res) {
    ...
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is online'));
```

Comment: its not simple when you have to add it to every route

Comment: you can use app.param() or router.param() or app.use() or router.use() with that you will not have to add it on every route.

Comment: This is actualy a great solution, but I would need the middleware to be inserted automatically on each endpoint to proceed this way. Is that possible ?....

Answer (score 0):

You can store the params on the `response.locals` object for use by later middleware.

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/:name', (request, response, next) => {
    // generate some kind of result
    const result = `Hello, ${request.params.name ?? 'world'}!`;
    // save the result and the params onto the request.locals object
    response.locals = { params: request.params, result };
    // call the next middleware to pass on the params and result
    next();
});

app.use((request, response, next) => {
    // here you have the params since they were parsed by the previous middleware
    console.log(`Intercepted: ${JSON.stringify(response.locals.params)}`);
    // now actually send the response that you wanted to send
    response.status(200).send(response.locals.result);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

This requires storing the `request.params` on the `response.locals` object in every handler, which is not the greatest. But it also means that you don't have to specify the interceptor middleware every time, if that's a problem for your case.

Comment: I am assuming that "I need the interception process to run before the endpoint" means you need it to run before the call to `response.send()`. If you need the interception process to run before the result is actually computed, then you can change `result` to a function and store that function on the `response.locals` object. Then when it comes time to proceed after the interception check, you can call that stored function to compute your actual result.